# Constraint trouble with concrete base models after migrating Django from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm attempting a migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL, and now I'm having trouble with concrete base classes. I have code similar to this:

```
class BaseKlass(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length = 64)

class SomeKlass(BaseKlass):
    value = IntegerField()
```

Whenever I create an instance of `SomeKlass`, I get an error like this:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "baseklass_ptr_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I looked at the SQL being executed, and indeed the value for `baseklass_ptr_id` was `null`.

Any idea?

Comment: As you have discovered, Postgres is a lot more strict than MySQL. +1 because it looks like you answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an owner for the `id` sequence solved the problem:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE myapp_baseklass_id_seq OWNED BY myapp_baseklass.id;
```